# Subtotal vs Subtotal (Excl. Tax) when creating a condition for discount rule

Tags: cart, tax, coupon-codes, subtotal

I'm creating a coupon code with a minimum order amount. While adding a condition, I'm not sure the difference between Subtotal and Subtotal (Excl. Tax). Could anyone help?[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a tax rule defined and the criteria is met for the customer i-e country etc, then the subtotal will be including tax and it's called just `subtotal` and if it's not then there won't be any tax on that subtotal and in that case it's called `Subtotal(Excl.Tax)`. Or you can say if you want to apply rule on subtotal but with tax excluding then select `Subtotal(Excl.Tax)` and vice versa.